# How can I make a SWF autoplay in the profile box of a facebook application?

Tags: facebook, autoplay

I want my SWF to autoplay in a Facebook profile box.  I am currently using an FBML based app but I am open to using any type that would make this easy. Using the param waitforclick=false does not work in the profile box so this is not an option.

At first I thought this would not be possible without using an AJAX request (that is what the docs say) but after trying to do this via AJAX with no luck, I did a bit more research.  I found that in the ReverbNation facebook application "My Band", they are able to autoplay a SWF. I haven't quite figured out how they do it yet but I did take a look at the generated profile box code before clicking the SWF and after clicking the SWF.

Before clicking:

```
<div id="2405167945_fbswf_4b0b4cce045f91534648943" height="15" width="15" overflow="hidden" class="__fbswf">
 <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash"    src="http://cache.reverbnation.com/widgets/content/player/facebookOneShot.swf?emailPlaylist=song_2509346&amp;autoPlay=true" 
  style="" id="swf_4b0b4cce049094f82894993" name="swf_4b0b4cce049094f82894993" bgcolor="000000" quality="high" 
  allowscriptaccess="never" fbjs="_id_4b0b4cce046032577161862" wmode="transparent"  flashvars="=&amp;fb_local_connection=_id4b0b4cce046320307815032&amp;fb_fbjs_connection=_id_4b0b4cce046032577161862&amp;fb_sig_profile=527222885&amp;fb_sig_locale=en_US&amp;fb_sig_in_new_facebook=1&amp;fb_sig_time=1259031758.018&amp;fb_sig_added=1&amp;fb_sig_profile_update_time=1239997072&amp;fb_sig_expires=1259038800&amp;fb_sig_user=527222885&amp;fb_sig_session_key=2.FMzt5_mR_LhrqF4nrQLhcg__.3600.1259038800-527222885&amp;fb_sig_ss=gAOI6rA0R_2tlubA5ahK_g__&amp;fb_sig_cookie_sig=2431e415604aec8066fce75f39769356&amp;fb_sig_ext_perms=auto_publish_recent_activity&amp;fb_sig_api_key=c3759de5d7120d6acc4dae494d1928be&amp;fb_sig_app_id=2405167945&amp;fb_sig=4cd04d06aae5296914b98fbae724b2cf&amp;string_table=http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/js_strings.php/t87432/en_US&amp;swf_id=swf_4b0b4cce049094f82894993" 
  width="15" height="15">
</div>
```

After clicking:

```
<div id="2405167945_fbswf_4b0b4d42660ba6dbafc86" height="15" width="15" overflow="hidden" class="__fbswf">
 <a height="15" width="15" waitforclick="true" 
 swfsrc="http://cache.reverbnation.com/widgets/content/player/facebookOneShot.swf?emailPlaylist=song_2509346&amp;autoPlay=true" 
 imgclass="rn_button_play_even" 
 imgsrc="http://cache.reverbnation.com/images/facebook/spacer.gif" 
 onclick="swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2 = new 
 SWFObject("http://cache.reverbnation.com/widgets/content/player/facebookOneShot.swf?emailPlaylist=song_2509346\x26autoPlay=true", 
 "swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2", 
 "15", "15", ["9.0.159.0","10.0.22.87"], "000000");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addParam("allowScriptAccess", "never");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addParam("fbjs", "_id_4b0b4d42660c73d7dd160");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addVariable("", "");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addVariable("fb_local_connection", "_id4b0b4d42699b33975134d");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addVariable("fb_fbjs_connection", "_id_4b0b4d42660c73d7dd160");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addVariable("fb_sig_profile", "527222885");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addVariable("fb_sig_locale", "en_US");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addVariable("fb_sig_in_new_facebook", "1");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addVariable("fb_sig_time", "1259031874.4381");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addVariable("fb_sig_added", "1");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addVariable("fb_sig_profile_update_time", "1239997072");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addVariable("fb_sig_expires", "1259038800");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addVariable("fb_sig_user", "527222885");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addVariable("fb_sig_session_key", "2.FMzt5_mR_LhrqF4nrQLhcg__.3600.1259038800-527222885");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addVariable("fb_sig_ss", "gAOI6rA0R_2tlubA5ahK_g__");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addVariable("fb_sig_cookie_sig", "2431e415604aec8066fce75f39769356");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addVariable("fb_sig_ext_perms", "auto_publish_recent_activity");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addVariable("fb_sig_api_key", "c3759de5d7120d6acc4dae494d1928be");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addVariable("fb_sig_app_id", "2405167945");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addVariable("fb_sig", "cd50d9ce65cfdac0100fd445fb041e9d");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addVariable("string_table", "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/js_strings.php/t87432/en_US");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.addVariable("swf_id", "swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2");
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.fallback_html = "\x3cdiv class=\x22flash_fallback\x22\x3e\x3cdiv class=\x22flash_fallback_border\x22\x3e\x3cdiv class=\x22flash_fallback_header\x22\x3eFlash Player upgrade required\x3c/div\x3e\x3cdiv class=\x22flash_fallback_explanation\x22 id=\x22flash_fallback_4b0b4d426c8fc1a1c5deb\x22\x3eYou must download and install the latest version of the Adobe Flash Player to view this content.\x3c/div\x3e\x3cdiv class=\x22flash_fallback_button\x22\x3e\x3cinput type=\x22button\x22 class=\x22inputbutton\x22 onclick=\x22this.disabled=true;getFlashPlayer();\x22 id=\x22\x22 name=\x22\x22 value=\x22Download Flash\x22 /\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/div\x3e";
swf_4b0b4d426c7a777aed2e2.write("2405167945_fbswf_4b0b4d42660ba6dbafc86");; (new Image()).src = '/ajax/ct.php?app_id=2405167945&amp;action_type=5&amp;post_form_id=957a92c32bf2dda6d7c4e508685c3718&amp;position=2&amp;' + Math.random(); return false;" href="#" flash="true"><img src="http://platform.ak.fbcdn.net/www/app_full_proxy.php?app=2405167945&amp;v=1&amp;size=p&amp;cksum=57619dca4b62f0b11a83d8c46cf2decd&amp;src=http%3A%2F%2Fcache.reverbnation.com%2Fimages%2Ffacebook%2Fspacer.gif" class="rn_button_play_even" width="15" height="15"></a></div>
```

Does anyone know how to make this autoplay feature happen?  I am really having trouble finding documentation anywhere on the internet.  I am also really not sure why the generated code changes to SWFObject code after clicking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its being passed as a flash param with their implementation:

```
src="http://cache.reverbnation.com/widgets/content/player/facebookOneShot.swf?emailPlaylist=song_2509346&amp;autoPlay=true"
```

How this is being implemented on their end i have no idea though.

Comment: That parameter seems to have no effect the SWF

Comment: Well its not going ot have an effect on YOUR swf - thats a paramer the SWF uses internally - or possibly that they JS is using somehow. Like i said - it looks like thats what they are using to flag autoplay - how they have actually implemented it on their end I dont know.

Comment: if i go to the URL of THEIR SWF with and without that param it auto plays.  not sure if that param only affects the SWF when it is embedded in fbook though.  either way, the SWF cannot control this internally according to facebook docs.  It has to be some FBJS or facebook related nuance that I haven't figured out.

Answer (score 1):

It's notable that while Facebook has done away with the ability to add tabs to PROFILE pages, you can still add them to FAN pages.  This continues to be supported.  How do you know which kind of page you have?  Well, if someone can friend you, you have a PROFILE page; if someone can LIKE you, then you have a FAN page.

The ReverbNation MyBand app doesn't use a basic FBML tab approach... it's a more robust canvas app.  In FBML, Auto play is disabled for "security and aesthetic reasons", according to the Dev Docs.  If you want to work around this, create a canvas app, so that you can make the necessary AJAX call.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/swf/